# Rails routes: param value a single dot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to add an route to rails application:

```
scope 'some_scope' do
  resources :some_resource, path: :resource, param: :name, constraints: { name: %r{.+} }, only: %i(update), format: false do
    put '/', as: :update, on: :collection, to: 'friendship_tags#update_collection'
  end
end
```

This works fine for all kind of url values, e.g. http://www.google.com, but considering dot-only values it seems completely broken.

the considered route is:

```
PUT /some_scope/some_resource/:name
```

they is also another route called: (this is route inside of block)

```
PUT /some_scope/some_resource
```

Now what happens is:

When I call

```
PUT /some_resource/.
```

Rails somehow interprets this as second url. (PUT /some_scope/some_resource)

When I call

```
PUT /some_scope/some_resource/..
```

There is an exception for routing:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PUT] "/some_scope")
```

When I call

```
PUT /some_scope/some_resource/...
```

Then everything is working fine.

Can someone help me out? I currently do not find a solution for that?

Comment: are you sure you want to use dots and these kind of things (http://www.google.com)  in the url?  wouldn't it be simpler to store records in db in a regular manner?

Comment: This is an API in a multi Rails-APP environment, and this url is to create a specific resource. In this case it should be possible to create dot-only values for that

Comment: Browser converts relative urls to absolute before sending a request. This process leads to removal of dot and double-dot path segments (which are interpreted as current level and previous level respectively)